# Ext js 6.6.0 : Ext.Msg.alert not working inside datefield change listeners

Tags: extjs

In below code when condition matches, ext alert is not shown on screen. When I debugged it I found that it is working in background but without having debug it ran so fast that it did not visible to user and go away.

Please let me know what wrong here:

```
{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    reference: 'endDate',
    fieldLabel: 'End Date',
    labelAlign: 'top',
    format: 'm/d/Y',
    editable: false,
    flex: 1,
    margin: '0 10',
    //allowBlank: false,
    //validateBlank: true,
    listeners: {
        change: function (me, newValue, oldValue, {}) {
            var endDate = me.lookupController().lookupReference('endDate').getValue();
            if (newValue <= endDate) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'End Date must be greater than Start Date');
                me.focus();
            } else if (newValue < Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'm/d/Y')) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'End Date cannot be less than todays Date');
                me.focus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share working code in sencha fiddle , there its easy to debug.

Comment: Please use this link -: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/301e
alert not working here!

Comment: Your fiddle link is not working please check once.

Comment: It is working now. I by mistake changed the version but revert my change now.Please check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please consider Date object when compare datefield values. And also check that showed alerts can be hidden back of a window etc.

Here is a working example for you: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/301k

Comment: Thanks Irfan for quick help.I found that Alert message is working without debug mode also but what happen in my case, I have a panel which is showing on a pop-up. When validation fail this alert message comes underneath the popup due to which it is visible to me. Now i am struggling with how can i pass custom class/style to Ext.Msg.alert so that its z-index can editied by new value. If you have any suggestion please let me know.

Comment: An alternative way i found is to use custom Ext.Msg.show({}) view having custom style set. also i come to know of using onTriggerClick () for only showing those values which are eligible as per business.